# How can i disable the relaying and use my code as an authenticated client?

Tags: c#, .net, iis, exchange-server

So there are many posts on this error i'm getting. But most deal with IIS.

> Mailbox unavailable. The server response was: 5.7.1 Unable to relay

I have ported my code to console to see if i still get this error, and i do. It would seem as though it's still using ISS as a relay or something even though this is a console application?

I have spoken to the Exchange Admin and he is not going to open up the mail server for any relaying or allow my server to do so. So i would like to make my C# code send out the email as a regular authenticated client as if it were outlook.

My code below works if i'm sending it to someone within my own domain but not if the recipient is outside the domain.

**How can i disable the relaying and use my code as an authenticated client so i can send emails to people outside my domain?**

CODE:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Sending Mail...");
    try
    {
        SmtpClient _SMTPServer = new SmtpClient("companymailserver", 587);
        _SMTPServer.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("myusername", "mypassword");

        MailMessage _mailMessage = new MailMessage();
        _mailMessage.To.Add(new MailAddress("someone@gmail.com"));
        _mailMessage.From = new MailAddress("myself@mycompanydomain.com");
        _mailMessage.IsBodyHtml = false;
        _mailMessage.Subject = "This is a test";
        _mailMessage.Body = "This is the body";

        _SMTPServer.Send(_mailMessage);
    }
    catch (Exception err)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("error: " + err.Message);
    }
    Console.WriteLine("Press any key to continue...");
    Console.Read();
}
```

---

**UPDATE #1**

The strange thing is no matter what credentials i put i get the same 'Unable to relay' error. As if it's defaulting to relay and ignoring my SmtpClient settings.

Comment: This is a outbound mail server setting, I don't think there is anything you can do code wise to allow this.

Comment: @kd7 Why wouldn't i be able to send out mail as a regular SmtpClient without relaying? after all the the Class is called `SmtpClient`. The server allows any authenticated clients to send out emails to anyone.

Comment: This should be possible, somehow.  Most mail servers will allow relaying, as long as the email is from a user with a mailbox on the system and the user is authenticated.  Otherwise, users would never be able to send email to other companies.

Comment: "Relaying" is actually exactly what you need here; It is where one SMTP server accepts a client's message and delivers it on to another server, instead of accepting it for local delivery. Your issue also seems to have nothing to do with IIS. Some versions of IIS comes with an SMTP service, which is why many questions on this topic mention IIS, but in your case you are specifying a particular server. Tim Larson's answer seems to be the direction you need to go here.

Comment: You can try to manually send a message with SMTP on the command line.  http://www.petri.co.il/smtp-authentication.htm.  It might help with the troubleshooting.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that the authentication failed.  Try including the domain name.

```
_SMTPServer.Credentials = 
    new System.Net.NetworkCredential("myusername", "mypassword", "mydomain");
```

Also, be sure to set UseDefaultCredentials to false

```
_SMTPServer.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
```

Comment: Try again - I added a note about UseDefaultCredentials that I forgot before

Comment: shoot, the `UseDefaultCredentials` sounded promising. But still same thing error and everything.